# undefined subroutine though defined

Tags: perl, module, undefined, subroutine

The most peculiar thing - to me anyway.
I have a module, lesenfantsterribles.pm, that contains all the common subroutines of a site. 
A subroutine called "Blacklist" is defined for use by other programs through `@EXPORT =` along with most of the subroutines except those only used in the module.

Suddenly, when called (`&Blacklist;`)from another subroutine in the module, I get the error message "Undefined subroutine &lesenfantsterribles::Blacklist called at lesenfantsterribles.pm line 681."

There are several possible calls to "Blacklist" in the subroutine and only one results in this error.

Any ideas?

The relevant snippet is this bit:

```
my $rc = &isSpamText($string);
&debugLog('isSpam',"return code from isSpamText <$rc>");
if ($rc)
{
    &errorLog('isSpam',"Probable spam comment '$string' - spam assumed");
    &Blacklist;
    return 1;   
}
```

Three internal subroutines are called successfully before this one is called and fails.

Comment: In what language is that? also, please format code properly. you can use the button with the "{ }" icon in the editor to do so

Comment: since you, litelite, don't recognise perl and can't see there is no code I doubt you could help. don't worry about it

Comment: Well, there are code snippets (extremely small but still existing). I did suspect it was perl from the extensions but did not wanted to jump to the gun and edit your post right off the bath. Also, tagging your language helps your question be seen. And would have helped you get an answer.

Comment: you are going to have to show your code, at least enough of it to duplicate the problem

Comment: Without seeing your code we would be guessing. And that's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @user1210923, may I ask you to strip down your code to a minimal example which exhibits the strange behaviour you describe. It may have to do with `package` settings, but that is hard to tell without such example code.

Comment: The relevant snippet is this:my $rc = &isSpamText($string);
 &debugLog('isSpam',"return code from isSpamText <$rc>");
 if ($rc)
 {
  &errorLog('isSpam',"Probable spam comment '$string' - spam assumed");
#  and stop him forever!
  &Blacklist;
  return 1; 
 }